# How to get the variable number of columns in a CSV file in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, awk, kdb

As part of a kdb q system that simply executes an awk command I can find the number of columns in a CSV file to load into kdb.

```
.helper.ux.getnumberofcolumns:{[filename]
  ncols:@[system;"awk -F, '{print NF; exit}' ",filename;()];
  :first {"I"$x} @/: ncols;}
```

The awk based system command is simply doing `awk -F, '{print NF; exit}' <filename>`

Is there a similar command I can use in Windows shell batch/cmd etc to accomplish the same thing? important without installing Cygwin (inside corp can't install it)

Comment: There is a port of awk (and almost all Linux shell commands) to windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all rows in the csv have the same number of fields, you can use the first record of the file to determine the number of fields in the file.

```
{count "," vs raze "head -1 ",x}
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell:

```
Get-Content .\awk.txt | %{ $a=$_.Split(','); Write-Host "No of fields in record="$a.length; break; }
```

More about this [here](http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.in/2009/06/awk-equivalent-in-windows-powershell.html).